# Java Concurrency with Sets

Tags: java, multithreading

For the below function, I am trying to return a new Set `mHashSet` that is a copy of another set `iGraphicSectors`:

```
public Set<String> getGraphics() {
    synchronized (iGraphicSectors) {  // class variable of type Set<String>
        LinkedHashSet<String> mHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        synchronized (mHashSet) {
            mHashSet.addAll(iGraphicSectors);
        }
        return mHashSet;
    }
}
```

However line 5 `mHashSet.addAll(iGraphicSectors);` is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` (I am not sure how this is possible).  Is there a way I can accomplish the above task in a thread-safe manner?

Comment: Yes, either change *all* code using `iGraphicSectors` to wrap it in a `synchronized (iGraphicSectors)`, *or* change `iGraphicSectors` to be class that is thread safe for iteration.

Comment: Synchronizing on `mHashSet` is unnecessary. There is no way, that any other thread could have a reference to that newly created set instance.

Comment: Side note: Since you just created `mHashSet`, and haven't shared it with anyone, there is no reason whatsoever for using `synchronized (mHashSet)`.

Comment: It is possible if any other thread modifies the set without synchronizing in it.

Comment: You should try to write a small test case that actually reproduces the issue.  I don't think you have identified the cause of the CME correctly.

Comment: Do you modify the content of `iGraphicSectors` often or rarely?

Comment: `iGraphicSectors` is modified often.  I think that is my mistake, I was assuming synchronizing `iGraphicSectors` here means no other function can modify it.

Comment: You want to make it immutable, consider : Collections.unmodifiableSet(...) upon returning the Set

Comment: Synchronizing on `mHashSet` accomplishes nothing because no other thread can possibly access the new object before your method returns.

Comment: Why do you synchronize on `iGraphicSectors`?  I'm guessing that you hope to prevent some other thread from modifying it, but does the other thread also synchronized on `iGraphicSectors`?  Synchronizing on an object does _not_ prevent other threads from accessing or modifying the object.  It only prevents them from synchronizing on it at the same time.

Comment: I'm synchronizing on `iGraphicSectors` to make sure it is not modified while I am iterating over it to make the new copy of the set.  Do I have to put in the individual `iGraphicSectors.add()` operations into synchronized blocks? i.e. `synchronized (iGraphicSectors) { iGraphicSectors.add(graphic); }`

Comment: Yes.  The `synchronized` block in your example will not stop other threads from modifying `iGraphicSectors`, but it _will_ stop other threads from entering `synchronized` blocks on the same object.  If you don't want the object to be modified by other threads while your `getGraphics()` method is running, then all of the places where it _could_ be modified must be synchronized too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to use a `Set` that is thread-safe for `iGraphicSectors` as you obviously read and modify it concurrently, the simplest way can be to use the decorator [`Collections.synchronizedSet(Set<T> s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet-java.util.Set-) to make your current `Set` thread-safe, any read and write accesses will then be automatically protected with a `synchronized` block thanks to the decorator, however you still need to protect iterations over it explicitly with a `synchronized` block.

Here is an example of how to create it:

```
Set<String> iGraphicSectors = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
```

Here is how your code would then look like:

```
public Set<String> getGraphics() {
    // Still needed as the constructor of LinkedHashSet will iterate
    // over iGraphicSectors 
    synchronized (iGraphicSectors) {  
        return new LinkedHashSet<String>(iGraphicSectors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there was also a concurrency wrapper for Sets, I will try this.  Although probably not necessary, just to be safe I may also add the below suggestion and return an unmodifiable mHashset.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not enough, you would move the problem outside your class, if you iterate over `Collections.unmodifiableSet(iGraphicSectors)` you can still get `ConcurrentModificationException` as it will still use the iterator from `iGraphicSectors`. If `iGraphicSectors` is read and modified concurrently, it must be thread-safe, it is the rule.

Comment: It's ok to `return Collections.unModifiableSet(new LinkedHashSet<>(iGraphicSectors));` just for extra safety from accidentally modifying that set, but that has nothing to do with concurrency and you still have to return a complete copy of the set anyway.

Comment: Do I have to put in the individual `iGraphicSectors.add()` operations into synchronized blocks? i.e. `synchronized (iGraphicSectors) {  
        iGraphicSectors.add(graphic);
    }`

Comment: No as it will be done internally by the decorator, only iterations over your set still need to be explicitly protected, check the javadoc for a better understanding

Comment: Thanks again, just wanted to confirm my understanding that when they say SynchronizedSet returns a threadsafe set for the "add" and "get" operations (for `iGraphicSectors` in my case), this is like "add" and "get" having to get the `iGraphicSectors` lock to run each time, so that any synchronized block (like for my iteration) with the `iGraphicSectors` lock will be free of "add" and "get" operations on `iGraphicSectors` for the duration the block is running, and that my earlier mistake was not using SynchronizedSet so that during the iteration of my set in the synchronized block, "add" CAN run

Comment: yes that is the idea, with your initial call you did not prevent potential concurrent call to `add `or `remove` while iterating over `iGraphicSectors` to build your safe copy such that you could end up with a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comments, it sounds like you simply want to make the `Set` immutable - which you can do without using any synchronization primitives with :

```
return Collections.unmodifiableSet(iGraphicSectors);
```

at the end of this function (See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet(java.util.Set))).

As a side note, it's fairly obvious that you don't want to use synchronization, as the `Set` is constructed locally within the function.  It does not have any visibility to other threads executing in your program.  If any synchronization is to take place, **it's not in this method**.

The real question is, will the `Set` returned by this method change?  If so, you can return a synchronized `Set` from this function with:

```
return Collections.synchronizedSet(...)
```

at the end of this function (again, see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set))).